# Replacement of elements in list based on index of another list

Tags: indexing, replace

This is my code:
time is a list with values from 60 to 900 with interval of 60.
PAR_2 is the list I want to modify. When time = 60 or a multiple of 60, the values in PAR_2 should be replaced by a fixed amount (50).

```
# here I try to go through two lists at the same time
for n, m in zip(time, PAR_2):
    if n[60] < n[90]:  ## If time is between 60 and 90, then I want the PAR_2=50
        m=50
print(PAR_2)
```

Output example:

```
time PAR_2
60    50
61    50
62    50
..    50
90    346
91    345
91    345
...   495
120   50
121   50
122   50
```

Comment: Your example is flawed and/or misleading, since 121 (or 61, 62, 122, for that matter) is not a multiple of 60.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
for i in range(len(PAR_2)):
 try:
  if time[i] % 60 == 0:
   PAR_2[i] = 50
 except IndexError: break
```

Comment: Thank you @Rfroes87, your code is a step forward, but I want the PAR_2 to be equal to 50, for the whole sequence between 60 and 90, and not only at 60. I was not clear

Comment: `interval=list(range(0, 900, 60))                                           
 for i in range(len(PAR_2)):                                                 
  try:                                                                                       
    if time[i]==interval[i]:                                   
      PAR_2[i:i+30] = 50                                                        
  except IndexError: break                                 
 `

Comment: I made some improvement, but now I substitute only the at the first element (0) of the interval, while I would like to subsitute also at 60, 120 and so on